# Delete Application Express Workspace

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I'm using oracle application express (11g) and i want to delete a workspace also a user.
Is possible can't find any resource on this.

Thanks

Comment: This link might be beneficial for this issue: [https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2301639](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2301639) Search for "workspace".

Answer (score 5):

You can find everything you need in the apex documentation, specifically [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21678/adm_wrkspc.htm#sthref171)

Basically, to administrate workspaces (and most of the apex related settings) you need to log in to the workspace 'internal', as admin.

Comment: in case you want to delete database username is this possible?

Comment: Mentioned answer link rot.